# Probability that quadratic is an ellipse

Tags: probability, polynomials

Let $p(x,y)$ be a quadratic equation with terms
$$ x^2 + y^2 + xy + x + y + 1\;, $$
where each term is multiplied by a random real coefficient uniformly 
distributed in $[-1,1]$.

> Q. What is the probability that $p(x,y)=0$ is an ellipse?

---

[image: ContourQuadratic]

          

<sup>Random quadratics.</sup>

---

Perhaps it is about 25%?

Comment: Do you mean of general form $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0$, where $a,\dots, f$ are randomly uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$?

Comment: HINT: Look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) . If you call $A,B,C,D,E,F$ the random coefficients uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, you have to compute the probability that $B^2-4AC <0$. If my calculation are not wrong, this should be $2/9$.

Comment: @b00nheT: Yes. Except distributed within $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Crostul: $2/9$ seems correct. Thanks!

Comment: Things are not so simple: It is not sufficient to check whether the quadratic form $Ax^2+By^2+Cxy$ is positive definite. There is a positive probability that the resulting set does not contain any real points at all, depending on $D$, $E$, and $F$. Note that all equations "in the neighborhood" of $x^2+y^2+1=0$ do not describe an ellipse.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Excellent point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of $A_Q$, the $3\times 3$ [matrix of the quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections)

$$Q(x,y) = Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0,$$ 
i.e.,

$$A_Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & B/2 & D/2 \\
  B/2 & C & E/2 \\
  D/2 & E/2 & F
\end{pmatrix},$$
the equation represents a real nondegenerate ellipse iff

1. $\det(A_{33}) > 0$, and
2. $(A+C)\det(A_Q) < 0$

where $A_{33}$ is the $2\times 2$ upper-left submatrix of $A_Q$:

$$A_{33} = \left( \begin{matrix}A & B/2\\B/2 & C\end{matrix}\right).$$

**NB**: Both conditions (1) and (2) are *homogeneous*; i.e., for any $k>0$, they hold for $(A,B,C,D,E,F)$ iff they hold for $(kA,kB,kC,kD,kE,kF)$. Consequently, the probability that the i.i.d. coefficients correspond to a real nondegenerate ellipse is invariant under rescaling of the distribution; e.g., if they are i.i.d. $\text{Uniform[-k,k]}$, then the answer is *the same for all $k>0$*.

---

**Simulations**

**R code**

Pending analytical solution of the posted question, here's a simulation (in R code, which defaults to using a Mersenne Twister PRNG) that simply samples the six coefficients (from $\text{Uniform}[-1,1]$) repeatedly and finds the proportion of times both of the above conditions are met:

```
library(conics)
nsamp = 10^8
count = 0
for (i in 1:nsamp){
  coeffs = runif(6,-1,1)      # sample the six coefficients
  AQ = conicMatrix(coeffs)    # AQ is the matrix of the conic
  det.AQ = det(AQ)
  det.A33 = det(AQ[1:2,1:2])  # det.A33 is -discrimant/4
  if (det.A33 > 0 & (coeffs[1]+coeffs[3])*det.AQ < 0){  
    count = count + 1
  }
}
print(count/nsamp)
```

Output:

```
 0.2738687
```

An approximate 95% confidence interval is therefore $0.2739 \pm 0.0001$.

**C code**

Essentially the same algorithm programmed in C, using two different PRNGs, gave the following consistent results for a much larger sample size:

```
PRNG                   Sample Size   95% Confidence Interval
------------------------------------------------------------
(a) Mersenne Twister      10^11        0.273898 +- 0.000003
(b) PCG                   10^11        0.273896 +- 0.000003
------------------------------------------------------------
(combined)              2 10^11        0.273897 +- 0.000002
```

(a) [mt19937-64](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt64.html), (b) [pcg-c-basic-0.9](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html#minimal-c-implementation).

Comment: Very nice! I had observed approximately $0.25$ with much smaller sample size, so this seems in line with that, and likely quite accurate. Thanks!